# Syntax Error while passing numeric column name in my update query of sql server in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am recently work on project in which I can add column dynamically with the `DateTime` now and this code works fine; but when I want to update this doesn't  work fine and *throw syntax error* and when ever I write character column name it works fine. Below is my code

```
cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
 "update attendance set '25.04.2017' =  '" + 
  abcd + 
 "'   where std_id = " + Convert.ToInt32(b) + "  ", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

where `abcd` is my column values which is `true` or `false` the issue with this '25.04.2017'

Comment: `add column dyanmically with the Data time now` - seriously now, don't do that!

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should swap field *name* (`abcd`) and its *value* (`25.04.2017`):

```
// Keep query 
//   1. Readable:     @
//   2. Paramterized: @prm_date, @prm_id
//   3. Formattable:  {abcd} (string interpolation)
string sql = 
  $@"update attendance
        set {abcd} = @prm_date -- field = value
      where std_id = @prm_id";

//DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
using (var cmd = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
  // Parametrize query
  //TODO: AddWithValue is not the best choice, turn into Add + Actual db type
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_date", new DateTime(2017, 4, 25));
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_id", b);

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**Edit:** In (for me very *improbable*) case that `'25.04.2017'` is a field *name* and `abcd` is its *value*:

```
string sql = 
  $@"update attendance
        set [25.04.2017] = @prm_abcd -- eerie field with '25.04.2017' name
      where std_id = @prm_id";

//DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
using (var cmd = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
  // Parametrize query
  //TODO: AddWithValue is not the best choice, turn into Add + Actual db type
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_abcd", abcd);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_id", b);

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @Andy Korneyev: I've re-read the question once again, and, yes, I shall confess, you can well be right; but what a *weird* choice of the field's name! I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have such a column named `25.04.2017` (I'd personally not recommend to do it) - you have to wrap such a name into square brackets:

```
"update attendance set [25.04.2017] =  '"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `25.04.2017` is a column name then you want to surround it with `[]`

```
update attendance set [25.04.2017] =  ....
```

Your code is vulnerable to sql injection when you append your parameter values as part of the sql string. Use Parameters instead for your values that you are passing.

Also your schema is not well designed any time you start using (*what should be*) values for columns. Instead I recommend a table with a column `AttendedOn` of type `DateTime2` and capture the value in there. It is very rare that you should ever have to dynamically create columns based on values and if that is the path you are on you should reconsider your design.